# WCF - Form posting not binding with model

Tags: c#, ajax, wcf, http-post

I have a form that I would like to submit using AJAX with WCF and the problem is that my Model("Client") doesn't get populate.
When I submit the Form it arrives to the Service but all the fields of "Client" are Null.
What am I missing here?

```
$("#myForm").on("submit", function (e) {
var Type = "POST";
var Url = "Service.svc/GetUser";
var Data = JSON.stringify($(this).serializeArray());
var ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";

$.ajax({
    type: Type, //GET or POST or PUT or DELETE verb
    url: Url,   // Location of the service
    data: Data, //Data sent to server
    contentType: ContentType, // content type sent to server
    processdata: true,
    success: function (result) {
        $("#myForm").remove();
    },
    error: function (result) {
        alert(result);
    }
});
});
```

IService:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST")]
void GetUser(Client client);
}
[DataContract]
public class Client
{
[DataMember(Name = "Name")]
public string Name { get; set; }
[DataMember(Name = "Phone")]
public string Phone { get; set; }
[DataMember(Name = "Email")]
public string Email { get; set; }
[DataMember(Name = "Message")]
public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

Service.cs:

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class Service : IService
{
public void GetUser(Client client) { }   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved!**

I sent a JSON array instead of a JSON object!
I found a very nice tool that takes the form inputs and create an object , it called jquery.serialize-object. You can install it using:
**bower install jQuery Serialize Object**

I hope it will help you guys.

Answer (score 3):

hello try sending values like this

```
var input = {"client": {
                "Name": $("#Name").val(),
                "Phone": $("#Phone").val(),
                "Email": $("#Email").val(),
                "Message": $("#Message").val()
            }};
  data: JSON.stringify(input),
```

By your code data is not sent to the service.

Comment: Hello, what does the stringify does?

Comment: it convert JavaScript value or  javascript object to a JSON string.